# Is it better for performance to dynamically change transition in JS directly, or using css classes instead?

Tags: javascript, performance, css, css-transitions

I have two elements that do a simple intro animation when scrolling. And I want to reverse the transition speed when going back.

Both these approaches work, but the site is kinda laggy so I was wondering which one is better for performance. Doing it in javascript like this..

```
function startAnimation(){
   elem1.classList.add('transformClass');
   elem2.classList.add('transformClass');

   elem1.style.transition = 'transform 0.6s';
   elem2.style.transition = 'transform 1.4s';
}

function exitAnimation(){
   elem1.classList.remove('transformClass');
   elem2.classList.remove('transformClass');

   elem1.style.transition = 'transform 1.4s'; //elem1 is now 1.4s instead of 0.6s
   elem2.style.transition = 'transform 0.6s';
}
```

or would it better to incorporate the transition into the added classes and using !important

```
function startAnimation(){
   elem1.classList.add('transformClass1');
   elem2.classList.add('transformClass2');
}

function exitAnimation(){
   elem1.classList.remove('transformClass1');
   elem2.classList.remove('transformClass2');
}

//CSS:

#elem1 {
   transition: transform 0.6s
}

#elem2 {
   transition: transform 1.4s
}

.transformClass1 {
   transition: transform 1.4s !important;
}

.transformClass2 {
   transition: transform 0.6s !important;
}
```

Comment: Have you profiled them in your browser to find out for certain? (I suspect the latter would be faster as it allows the browser to potentially precompile the animation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're some conditions in this test that I've done with your code.

- 1. There's no HTML codes given to me - I had to make my own HTML codes, which means, this result might not be the one from the same source.
- 2. The website I've used to test JavaScript codes does not support to make an external CSS file, which means, I had to put `<style></style>` tag with HTML, so it might be different from adding an external CSS file.
- 3. The number of executing each codes is about 3,000.
- 4. [Related to #2] Since I had to put `<style></style>` in HTML, that means, the codes that is consist of only JavaScript couldn't be run with the codes consist of JavaScript and CSS, together, because as I mentioned `<style>` tag, it affects both. So I had to run them separately.

Here's HTML I made:

```
<div id="elem1"></div>
<div id="elem2"></div>
<div class="transformClass1"></div>
<div class="transformClass2"></div>
```

And here's the result I've got:
[image]

Gray - Only JavaScript
Green - JavaScript + CSS
**Lower is better**

※ Website I've used - http://jindo.dev.naver.com/jsMatch

made by Naver, from South Korea

Comment: As I said several times, the result always can be different depending on the conditions.

Comment: Sweet, that's what I suspected too. I'm not too concerned about using <style> instead of an external file cause that's what I'm doing anyways. Thanks!

Comment: @MagdiGamal No problem. I could also learn by you, by testing this codes!